# vue.js - dynamic html tag (using variable)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I was wondering if there was any way to dynamically set the tags of an html element. E.g.

```
var element = "ol";

<{element}> some content </{element}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into [Render Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), `jsx` is also supported in Vue.js2.
Here's a simple example.

```js
var element = 'ol'

Vue.component('custom', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
      element,
      this.$slots.default
    )
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom>abc</custom>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is scoped is it?

Comment: Sorry but not sure what you need, do scoped slots help? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots

Comment: Like, if I were to use `<custom></custom>` in a separate file would it still render it as `<ol>` or as `<custom></custom>`

Comment: Got it. I think it depends on the way you register your component.   `Vue.component` is used for global registration which means the component registered will be exposed everywhere. However, we are allowed to use local registration to solve this problem. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration

Comment: ah cool, I guess I'll have to think about it more about how to incorporate all of this and make it work and locally scoped lol

Answer (score 5):

Easier method is to just use `component` element, like this:

```
<component :is="elType">...</component>
```

Just set `elType` in data to whatever type of element you want it to be (ie `div`, `h1` etc)

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-kapitsa-zbtok?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark